# gnome terminal + vim's directory browser = underlines

Tags: vim, gnome-terminal, styles, highlighting

Opening a directory up in Vim (using gnome-terminal) looks like this:

[image]

Notice the underline that shows which line we're currently on? Can this underline be changed or removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This command should remove the underline:

```
:hi cursorLine cterm=NONE gui=NONE
```

Answer (score -1):

You may avoid that by using NerdTree:
http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1658